# merge pandas dataframe causing duplicate row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas dataframe that I want to merge. My first dataframe, `names`, is a list of stock tickers and corresponding dates. Example below:

```
    Date    Symbol  DateSym
0   2017-01-05  AGRX    AGRX01-05-2017
1   2017-01-05  TMDI    TMDI01-05-2017
2   2017-01-06  ATHE    ATHE01-06-2017
3   2017-01-06  AVTX    AVTX01-06-2017
4   2017-01-09  CVM CVM01-09-2017
5   2017-01-10  DFFN    DFFN01-10-2017
6   2017-01-10  VKTX    VKTX01-10-2017
7   2017-01-11  BIOC    BIOC01-11-2017
8   2017-01-11  CVM CVM01-11-2017
9   2017-01-11  PALI    PALI01-11-2017
```

I created another dataframe, `price1`, that loops through the tickers and creates a dataframe with the open, high, low, close and other relevant info I need. When I `merge` the two dataframes together, I want to only show the `names` dataframe on the left with the corresponding price data on the right. What I ran a test of the first 10 tickers, I noticed that the combined dataframe is outputting redundant rows. (See CVM in row 4 and 5 below), even though the `price1` dataframe doesn't have duplicate values. What am I doing wrong?

```
def price_stats(df):
    # df['ticker'] = df
    df['Gap Up%'] = df['Open'] / df['Close'].shift(1) - 1
    df['HOD%'] = df['High'] / df['Open'] - 1
    df['Close vs Open%'] = df['Close'] / df['Open'] - 1
    df['Close%'] = df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift(1) - 1
    df['GU and Goes Red'] = np.where((df['Low'] < df['Close'].shift(1)) & (df['Open'] > df['Close'].shift(1)), 1, 0)
    df['Yday Intraday>30%'] = np.where((df['Close vs Open%'].shift(1) > .30), 1, 0)
    df['Gap Up?'] = np.where((df['Gap Up%'] > 0), 1, 0)
    df['Sloppy $ Vol'] = (df['High'] + df['Low'] + df['Close']) / 3 * df['Volume']
    df['Prev Day Sloppy $ Vol'] = (df['High'].shift(1) + df['Low'].shift(1) + df['Close'].shift(1)) / 3 * df[
        'Volume'].shift(1)

    df['Prev Open'] = df['Open'].shift(1)
    df['Prev High'] = df['High'].shift(1)
    df['Prev Low'] = df['Low'].shift(1)
    df['Prev Close'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
    df['Prev Vol'] = df['Volume'].shift(1)
    df['D-2 Close'] = df['Close'].shift(2)
    df['D-2 Vol'] = df['Volume'].shift(2)

    df['D-3 Close']= df['Close'].shift(3)
    df['D-2 Open'] = df['Open'].shift(2)
    df['D-2 High'] = df['High'].shift(2)
    df['D-2 Low'] = df['Low'].shift(2)
    df['D-2 Intraday Rnage'] = df['D-2 Close']/df['D-2 Open']-1
    df['D-2 Close%'] = df['D-2 Close']/df['D-3 Close']-1

    df.dropna(inplace=True)

vol_excel = pd.read_excel('C://U******.xlsx')
names = vol_excel.Symbol.to_list()

price1 = []
price1 = pd.DataFrame(price1)

for name in names[0:10]:

    print(name)
    price = yf.download(name, start="2016-12-01", end="2022-03-04")
    price['ticker'] = name
    price_stats(price)
    price1 = pd.concat([price1, price])


price1 = price1.reset_index()

orig_day = pd.to_datetime(price1['Date'])
price1['Prev Day Date'] = orig_day - pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(1, holidays=nyse.holidays().holidays)
price1['DateSym'] = price1['ticker']+ price1['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
price1 = price1.rename(columns={'ticker':'Symbol'})


datesym = price1['DateSym']
price1.drop(labels=['DateSym'], axis=1,inplace = True)
price1.insert(0, 'DateSym', datesym)


vol_excel['DateSym'] = vol_excel['Symbol']+vol_excel['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
dfcombo = vol_excel.merge(price1,on=['Date','Symbol'],how='inner')
```

See how CVM is duplicated twice when i print out dfcombo

```
Date    Symbol  DateSym_x   DateSym_y   Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume  ... Prev Vol    D-2 Close   D-2 Vol D-3 Close   D-2 Open    D-2 High    D-2 Low D-2 Intraday Rnage  D-2 Close%  Prev Day Date
0   2017-01-05  AGRX    AGRX01-05-2017  AGRX01-05-2017  2.71    2.71    2.40    2.52    2.52    2408400 ... 18584900.0  5.000   2390400.0   5.700000    5.770   5.813000    4.460   -0.133449   -0.122807   2017-01-04
1   2017-01-05  TMDI    TMDI01-05-2017  TMDI01-05-2017  15.60   16.50   12.90   13.50   13.50   43830   ... 114327.0    10.500  61543.0 7.200000    7.500   10.500000   7.500   0.400000    0.458333    2017-01-04
2   2017-01-06  ATHE    ATHE01-06-2017  ATHE01-06-2017  2.58    2.60    2.23    2.42    2.42    222500  ... 1750700.0   1.930   53900.0 1.750000    1.790   1.950000    1.790   0.078212    0.102857    2017-01-05
3   2017-01-06  AVTX    AVTX01-06-2017  AVTX01-06-2017  1.24    1.24    1.02    1.07    1.07    480500  ... 1246100.0   0.883   44900.0 0.890000    0.896   0.950000    0.827   -0.014509   -0.007865   2017-01-05
4   2017-01-09  CVM CVM01-09-2017   CVM01-09-2017   2.75    3.00    2.75    2.75    2.75    376520  ... 414056.0    2.000   77360.0 2.000000    2.000   2.250000    2.000   0.000000    0.000000    2017-01-06
5   2017-01-09  CVM CVM01-09-2017   CVM01-09-2017   2.75    3.00    2.75    2.75    2.75    376520  ... 414056.0    2.000   77360.0 2.000000    2.000   2.250000    2.000   0.000000    0.000000    2017-01-06
6   2017-01-10  DFFN    DFFN01-10-2017  DFFN01-10-2017  111.00  232.50  108.75  125.25  125.25  165407  ... 43167.0 30.900  67.0    34.650002   31.500  34.349998   30.900  -0.019048   -0.108225   2017-01-09
7   2017-01-10  VKTX    VKTX01-10-2017  VKTX01-10-2017  1.64    1.64    1.43    1.56    1.56    981700  ... 1550400.0   1.260   264900.0    1.230000    1.250   1.299000    1.210   0.008000    0.024390    2017-01-09
8   2017-01-11  BIOC    BIOC01-11-2017  BIOC01-11-2017  858.00  1017.00 630.00  813.00  813.00  210182  ... 78392.0 306.000 5368.0  285.000000  285.000 315.000000  285.000 0.073684    0.073684    2017-01-10
9   2017-01-11  CVM CVM01-11-2017   CVM01-11-2017   4.25    4.50    3.00    3.75    3.75    487584  ... 672692.0    2.750   376520.0    2.750000    2.750   3.000000    2.750   0.000000    0.000000    2017-01-10
```

I'm wondering since the `names` dataframe may have the same tickers, but different dates, in the dataframe and each time the `price1` dataframe is pulling the price data and adding to that `price1` dataframe maybe causing the issue.

For example, in the `names` dataframe, AGRX can be listed for the date 2017-01-05 and 2020-12-20. My loop function as shown pulls from yahoo data and appends it to the `price1` dataframe even though its the same set of data. Along the same token, is there a way for me to skip appending that duplicate ticker and will that solve the issue?

Comment: Please could you reduce your post to only include relevant information/code? For example, if your issue is just with the `merge`, you could provide samples of both your DataFrames (using `vol_excel.head(10).to_dict()` and `price`.head(10).to_dict()`) and the part of the code that has the `merge` statement.

Comment: I'm guessing `price1=price1.drop_dulicates()` before the merge will solve you issue.  Sure you could prevent this by taking the min/max dates of each ticker from the first df and passing those to your `yf.download` loop, but maybe that's not worth the effort.